# function binding not working between 2 directives

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to bind a function to a directive. Here is my fiddle code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("myFoo", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            callback: '&'  
        },
        template: '<span ng-click="callback()">MyFoo</span>'
    };
});

myApp.directive("myBar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",       
        template: '<div>MyBar > <my-foo test="cb"></my-foo></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.cb = function (x) {console.log('click');}    
        }
    };
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/448/)

I must be doing something stupid because the callback is not working when I click the `my-foo` element. Any suggestions why this example doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it into the attribute you're using which is callback, also associate it directly with an '=':

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("myFoo", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            callback: '='  
        },
        template: '<span ng-click="callback()">MyFoo</span>'
    };
});

myApp.directive("myBar", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",       
        template: '<div>MyBar > <my-foo callback="cb"></my-foo></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.cb = function (x) {console.log('click');}    
        }
    };
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xohv1syq/

jsFiddle using &: http://jsfiddle.net/hzxcptzv/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I though that `&` was always used to bind functions. Can you explain why `&` doesn't work here ? In the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) I red that `&` is ideal for callback function binding

Comment: You can use &, just make sure you pass it in correctly. Look at my second jsFiddle. I.e. it should be callback="cb()"

Comment: Thanks a lot, (reading the documentation a couple of times) it all makes sense now!!